What's wrong with nicematrix and socg-lipics-v2021.cls?
Sorry for asking for help to understand a custom conference class file. The class file is a wrapper available here around the LIPIcs class file. When compiling a basic document such as
\documentclass{socg-lipics-v2021}
\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}

I already get a warning LaTeX Warning: Command \LT@start  has changed. Even worse, when trying to use nicematrix with this package:
\documentclass{socg-lipics-v2021}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}

I get errors Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \begin{document} right at the \begin{document}. There's much happening in both class files, and I have no clue what causes this interaction. I'm using nicematrix version 2024/08/22, if that matters.

You can use the notab option which will prevent the class from redefining the tabular environment:
\documentclass[notab]{socg-lipics-v2021}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}


That saved my day. Did you find that from reading the source or the manual?

@Bubaya The source. My debugging process was to first try to directly use lipics-v2021.cls without the wrapper. This worked and thus the problem could only be in socg-lipics-v2021. Which is only a couple of independent blocks with "fixes", so easy to narrow down.
